# Gremlin - filtering Edges from a zipped list of property values

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I have two properties on my Edges that I want to filter on: `a` and `b`. I want to filter these properties using the following list:

```
lst = [['0102', '2017-01-01'], ['4920', '2018-07-01'], ..., ['2198', '2018-04-01']]
```

... and using the following logic:

```
('a1' AND 'b1') OR ('a2' AND 'b2') OR ... OR ('an' AND 'bn')
```

For filtering the Edges on a single one of the value pairs in `lst` I could:

```
g.E().and(has('a', '0102'), has('b', '2017-01-01'))
```

For filtering on all of them, I could:

```
s.E().or(and(has('a', '0102'), has('b', '2017-01-01')), 
         and(has('a', '4920'), has('b', '2018-07-01')),
         ...
         and(has('a', '2198'), has('b', '2018-04-01')))
```

The approach works, **but** requires manually inputing the filter parameters. It will therefore break as soon as the contents of variable `lst` changes.

Is there a way to, given the format of variable `lst`, computationally solve this problem by passing `lst` into the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
g.E().as('e').
  filter(constant(lst).unfold().as('t').
         where('e', eq('t')).
           by('a').
           by(limit(local, 1)).
         where('e', eq('t')).
           by('b').
           by(tail(local, 1)))
```

However, note, that it will be a full scan over all edges, and that performance will further decrease with increasing size of `lst`.

If your edges are globally indexed (I don't remember if that's even possible in JG), you'd probably see better/faster results if you execute `N` queries in parallel (where `N` is the number of entries in `lst`).